# Mix of Inheritance + Inclusion tags

Tags: django, django-templates

We know about "extend" inheritance tag and inclusion tags. What about the combination of it, like an asp.net grid templates.

Like this:

```
{% template %}
   {% content top %}some html{% endcontent %}
   {% content bottom %}some html{% endcontent %}
{% endtemplate %}
```

UPD:
Is there such tags already developed?

Comment: Is there such tags already developed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer:

http://code.google.com/p/django-tag-include/

http://blog.dynback.com/index.php/2009/08/django/django-inheritance-include-tag/

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you can't mix override `{% block %}` tags that came from an `{% include %}` in the base template.

If [#6646](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6646) gets committed, you'll be able to do this (for static `{% include %}` tags at least).